# Сбор метрик Sql Server и сохранение их в таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите как можно организовать сбор метрик/логов Sql Server, интересуют данные какие запросы выполнялись и время выполнение, метрики так же записывать в таблицу Sql Server. В дальнейшем буду выводить метрики в Grafana

Comment: Если SQLсервер версии 2016 и выше, то не изобретайте велосипед, а посмотрите в сторону активации [Query Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) и использования прилагающихся к нему [Query Store Catalog Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#query-store-catalog-views).

Comment: @denis-rubashkin спасибо!